# is it possible to print different lines to different output files using awk

Tags: awk

I want to print different lines to different output files using awk, depending on different conditions, like

```
awk '{if($2>10) print > outfile1; else print > outfile2}' infile
```

but this script doesn't work
how to modify it?
thanks!>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to close the file names in double quotes:

```
awk '{if($2>10) {print > "outfile1"} else {print > "outfile2"}}' infile
```

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this :

```
awk '{if($2>10) print > "outfile1"; else print > "outfile2"}' infile
```

If you ommit `"`, you are redirecting to (possibly non existing) variables. In my case, I redirect to files.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print > "outfile" ($2>10 ? 1 : 2)}' infile
```

Comment: Hey - this is a shot in the dark that I get a response but... awk puts `"outfile"` into the directory of the input file (or at least that's what it is doing for me right now).  Is there anyway I can change the directory?  I'm using a dynamic file name, too... `... file = sprintf(...); print > file; ...`

Comment: Sure, just specify whatever path you like, e.g. `print > "../outfile"` or `print > "/usr/tmp/outfile"` or whatever you need.

Comment: nevermind... i just answered it myself.  sorry. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go over it two times instead.

```
cat infile | awk '{if($2>10) print}' > outfile; cat infile | awk '{if($2<=10) print}' > outfile2
```

Comment: a) don't do that, and b) if you are then do it awk-ishly: awk '$2>10' infile > outfile; awk '$2<=10' infile > outfile.

Answer (score 0):

Quote your destination file names in double-quotes, and you're good to go.