# Find which row having less columns using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file where there are 4 fields expected for each row. If there are less number of fields then I want to write that information in a logfile with the row number.

```
Filed1line1| Filed2line1| Filed3line1| Filed4line1
Filed1line2| Filed2line2| 
Filed1line3| Filed2line3| Filed3line3| Filed4line3
```

Something like - Row number 2 is having 3 fields for file a.txt

Can we achieve this using awk.

Actually I am using the below code snippet. If the number of fields is <> 4 then I am writing it in a bad file. that is working good. But I am unable to write NR value in log.

```
 awk -F'|' -v DGFNM="$IN_DIR$DGFNAME" -v DBFNM="$IN_DIR$DBFNAME" '
    $1 == "DTL" {
     if (NF == 4) {
       print substr($0, 5) > DGFNM
     } else {
       print > DBFNM
       print NR >> $logfile
     }
    }
   ' "$IN_DIR$IN_FILE"
```

Comment: `awk 'NF < 4 {print NR}'` will print the row number of a row with less than 4 columns.

Comment: define a new variable for logfile (similar to other two), also no need to use `>>`, it will by default append with `>` (similar to other two).

Comment: How did you know the syntax to use `DGFNM` and `DBFNM` correctly but not `logfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: NF is the number of fields in the record and NR is the record number.

Something like: `awk '{ if (NF < 4) { print "Row " NR " has " NF " fields"; } }'` - there are shorter ways, but I prefer longer code that is easier to read ;-)

See this question for some info on printing to different output files: [is it possible to print different lines to different output files using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077631/is-it-possible-to-print-different-lines-to-different-output-files-using-awk)

To answer your edited question: `$logfile` is inside the single quotes, so it is not expanded to your shell variable logfile. And it is not an "awk" variable. try `print NR >> "some_file";` in the awk, and then rename some_file to $logfile later.

Another option would be to generate the awk file with the expanded $logfile already in place instead of trying to do it inline.

Comment: The option worked for me - "To answer your edited question: $logfile is inside the single quotes, so it is not expanded to your shell variable logfile. And it is not an "awk" variable. try print NR >> "some_file"; in the awk, and then rename some_file to $logfile later".